# Add a self-contained API to an existing rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We want to add the routes defined by an LDAP authorization application (a pure API application) to our core rails application, under the path `/ldap-auth`.

We have the option to use any technology we want for the LDAP authorization application -- we could write it with rails-api, Sinatra, even pure rack -- though we lean toward rails for codebase consistency.  The key point is that it's a self-contained application, with its own tests and release schedule.

What would be the most idiomatic rails technology for this use case?  Reading the guides it seems that a [rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) or a mounted [Rails API app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) are the natural possibilities.

My questions are:

1. What factors should guide my choice of one over the other?
2. The Engine guide states that "engines and applications can be thought of as almost the same thing, just with subtle differences, as you'll see throughout this guide."  However, even after reading through the guide, it's still unclear to me why one would choose to use an engine, versus mounting an ordinary rails app.  I'd appreciate clarification on this point.

Finally, if we do decide to go with a mounted rails API application, we'd like to keep it in the same repo.  Where is the most idiomatic place to the code?  Under `/lib`?